# Android Tablet Restored, Can't Reinstall Same Apps

Tags: google-play-store, asus-eee-pad-transformer

My Android tablet 'broke'.  Sent it in to the OEM and they fixed it under warranty and shipped it back.  Now, when I go to re-install certain apps, they won't install to my tablet because Google Play says they're "already installed".  But the OS was reloaded and they are no longer installed.  How do I re-install my apps without repaying?

Comment: Have you tried installing from the web version of the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

You could try factory resetting you tablet. Not sure if it might help. It's worth a try.

Comment: It was ‘‘factory reset'' when I got it back from ASUS.